# html tags are added while copying plain text from qTextEdit to LibreOffice Writer (<!--StartFragment--> and <!--EndFragment-->)

Tags: python, html, qt, tags, libreoffice

I write a simple program in Python and Qt to convert symbols. I use qTextEdit for both user input and for display of the converted text. Both widgets are using only plain text. I also have a push button "copy converted text". Everything works fine, but when I copy converted text (`textEdit.copy()`) and paste it into LibreOffice Writer two html tags are added to the text: `<!--StartFragment-->` *my_text* `<!--EndFragment-->` as two comments. How do I get rid of them?

Comment: It would help to first know whether these tags are added by Qt or by LibreOffice. Do you also have them when pasting in Notepad for example ?

Comment: No, they are only in LibreOffice, but not in plain text editors. I cannot check with other word processors or with Word.